# Measure theoretic reason why i.i.d. random variables have the same expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X, Y$ two independent and identically distributed real random variables.

Does it hold that $\forall A \in \mathfrak{F}$ we have $$\mathbb{E}[X : A] = \mathbb{E}[Y : A] $$

Comment: No, it doesn't. Consider for instance a symmetric random variable $X$ and set $Y:=-X$.

Comment: @saz what if they are non negative?

Comment: Doesn't change anything; still not true.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by $\mathbb E[X:A]$ you mean the conditional probability usually denoted as $\mathbb E[X|A]$.

The statement is false. Take $X$ and $Y$ two i.i.d [Bernoulli variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with $p\neq1$ and consider the event $A=\{X=1\}$. Then $\mathbb E[X|A]=1$, but by independence $\mathbb E[Y|A] = \mathbb E[Y] = p \neq 1$.